# Access to undeclared static property: Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::

Tags: php, doctrine, mongodb

I'm facing this critical issue on all my Documents which have either an @ODM\UniqueIndex, @ODM\InheritanceType,  @ODM\DiscriminatorField,  etc field defined for. Basically, if there's anything more than an @ODM\Document annotation for the class, I get the error below while trying to retrieve a document using the DocumentManager:

For some reason it's trying to access a static property with weird characters like $D7�1, etc. What's happening? Could someone please help me resolve this as we've hit a roadblock in our project due to this. The latest master branch of the ODM is being used.

**Note: This exception only happens to be thrown when APC is enabled. If I disable APC and restart apache, it works fine. Also when APC is enabled, it works on the first load, but fails for every consecutive request. (Guess this is happening because the APC opcode cache is populated only after the first request)**

### Error

```
Fatal error: Access to undeclared static property: Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver::$�S in /home/dayson/projects/www/textme/ninja/library/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Mapping/Driver/AnnotationDriver.php on line 146

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
.....
6   0.0037  1319032 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager->find( )   ../Test.php:34
7   0.0038  1322736 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager->getRepository( )  ../DocumentManager.php:574
8   0.0038  1322736 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager->getClassMetadata( )   ../DocumentManager.php:474
9   0.0038  1322736 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->getMetadataFor( )    ../DocumentManager.php:273
10  0.0038  1322736 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory->loadMetadata( )  ../ClassMetadataFactory.php:180
11  0.0050  1495432 Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver->loadMetadataForClass( )   ../ClassMetadataFactory.php:243
```

### Code

```
$dm->find('Document\User', '4e283aabc2749a4b7d0001dd')
```

### Document Code

```
<?php
namespace Document;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Mapping\Annotations as ODM;

/**
 * @ODM\Document
 * @ODM\UniqueIndex(keys={"mobile"="asc"})
 */
class User extends \Document\AbstractDocument
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ODM\Id
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ODM\String
     */
    protected $mobile;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug with APC 3.1.3p1. I upgraded to version 3.1.9 and it's now resolved.

Hope this saves some time for other people who may encounter it in the future. Do not use the APC packages from the debian/ubuntu repositories. Use the PECL one instead.